# Making a JFrame and Observable Object

Tags: java, swing, observer-pattern, observable

I have a class let's say `MyJFrame` which represent the GUI of my application. It implements the interface `Observer` and override the method `update`.

```
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame implements Observer{
  ...
  public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1){
     ...
  }
}
```

Now I want to make also my JFram an Observable object but I can't because it already extend the class `JFrame`. I tried to create a variable of type Observable in my class.

```
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame implements Observer{
  Observable observable = new Observable();
```

The problem here is that I can add Observer to this observable field and I can also notify the observer but I cannot invoke the method `setChanghed()` (because it is declared as protected) which has to be called before the notification.

Do you have any idea about I can implement it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend `Observable` and declare `setChanged()` public.

Comment: Can you be more detailed please? Thanks!

Comment: When you extend a class, you can redeclare its methods with a visibility modifier that is higher than it previously was. Since `Observable`s `setChanged()` was protected, you can create a subclass of `Observable` with `setChanged()` being public.

Comment: I don't now way but I was sure that it was not possible modify the visibility of a method. Thanks, it works!

Comment: You might also want to look at Hovercraft's answer. People tend to go with `PropertyChangeListener`s as opposed to `Observable` / `Observer`.

Comment: So it is possible to increase the visibility but not to decrease, right? It's the same for the variable? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I think many here, myself included use the [Observer Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_design_pattern) without using Java's formal `Observer/Observable` interface/class, and there are many ways to implement this, especially in Swing. Probably the most flexible is to use `PropertyChangeSupport` with `PropertyChangeListeners` which is how SwingWorkers implement this. Another is to use the very basic ChangeListener interface.

If you need more specific help, please provide more detail on your problem and likely we can offer suggestions.

**Edit 1**
This also alights on a separate but important issue that's suggested by the description of your program: your GUI class extending JFrame. Many here (again myself included) recommend that you should avoid doing this unless your code alters the intrinsic behavior of JFrame -- that is that your class overrides one or more of JFrame's methods.  This is a small sub-discussion in the much greater discussion on which is better: enhancing classes through inheritance or through composition.

For example: [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

**Edit 2**
Next unrequested recommendation: I try to gear my GUI code toward creating JPanels rather than JFrames. This way if I want to display my GUI as a stand-alone GUI, I simply create a JFrame on the fly, place my gui's JPanel into the JFrame's contentPane, pack the JFrame and display it. I do the same procedure if I want to place the gui into a JDialog, a JApplet, a JOptionPane, or also in a CardLayout using container, another JPanel,... . This gives me tremendous flexibility in how I use my gui's.

Comment: So you are sayng that if I want to make a GUI is better to declare JFrame as a variable of my class and use it?

Comment: PropertyChangeListeners + SwingWorkers, instead of Observable +1

Comment: @lucaghera: I can't say what is better for your situation with 100% accuracy, but myself I prefer not to extend JFrame if I can avoid doing so and am usually successful at doing this.

Comment: It's funny, because the Eclipse plugin WindowBuilder do the same that I did. But I think that both the versions work ;)

Comment: @lucaghera: Nothing funny about it, and this is yet another reason that I don't like to use gui builder tools. :)

Comment: @lucaghera: also another unrequested recommendation in my answer in **Edit 2** above.

Comment: I really like it! And I agree!

Comment: [Followup question on why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034477/why-property-change-listener-instead-of-observable)

Answer (score 2):

This will do it.

```
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame implements Observer {
    private static class MyObservable extends Observable {
        @Override
        public void setChanged() {
            super.setChanged();
        }
    }
    private final MyObservable observable = new MyObservable();

    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: maybe correct for OP, but there I think that for this implementations output to the GUI must be wrapped into invokeAndWait(),