# Why property change listener instead of observable

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns

I was having problems with class design until i found out about observable (using observer design pattern) and thus created a small application using it which solved my problem. I was happy and proud that I had used a good principle to sovle a problem.

Now i am about to start my main application and have just read this

[Making a JFrame and Observable Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968490/making-a-jframe-and-observable-object)

Why is the poster advised against the use of observable and instead told to use propertychangelistenr? Is there any issues with using observable?

Regards

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Observer and Listener pattern are very similar. But Observer has a weakness: all observables are the same. You have to implement the logic that is based on `instanceof` and cast object to concrete type into `Observable.update()` method.

Listeners are different. There are a lot of listener types. For example mouse listener, keyboard listener etc. Each one has several callback methods (i.e. `keyPressed()`, `keyReleased()` etc). So, you never have to implement the logic that should answer the question "is it my event" into the event handler.

I think that this is why listener model is preferable.

Comment: What do you mean "all observables are the same"?

Comment: Observable had only one handler for all events and has to implement logic that distinguishes among them. Listener has handler per event type, so the implementation is free of a boilerplate code.

Comment: Now it's clear, it's a little wording issue that I use the word "observer" for your "observable".

Answer (score 7):

DejanLekic and others have probably by now realized, that `Observable` is not an `interface`.  That is the whole problem with `Java.util.Observable`!

The user of `Observable` has to inherit from it, and nothing else.

Consider `Java.RMI` or `Listener events`.

Answer (score 3):

The only right answer is "it depends".

`Observable` is good when you don't care what changes about an object; you only want to know that *something* changed and update e.g. a cache of object properties. It's interface is just too coarse, but it could be a time-saver if you just have a need for such a thing.

On the other hand, as AlexR noticed, you also don't know what type of argument gets passed in before hand (it can even be a `null` value!). This makes it harder to do something useful with it. A proper listener class can have a richer API, but at the cost of adding a Listener interface and event class to your project.

Answer (score 1):

PropertyChangeListener is a special case of the Observable pattern. That is I guess that both solution is good from a design perspective. Meanwhile as far as I remember PropertyChangeListener has some built in support hence it might require less coding. Ie. see: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in how you use them. Most of the time subclasses of Observable have no particular implementation - you inherit from it just to get a new type of Observable. Listeners on the other hand implement particular interface (or top level EventListener interface) and therefore MUST implement certain methods.